# Django admin: How to allow users to edit the profile?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-profiles

I tried to implement the code for editing the Django admin panel. It ran without any errors, but it did not update the relevant data fields in the database. Here is my code for updating the database table.

**views.py**

```
   @login_required
   def edit_profile(request):
    if request.POST:
    if 'logout' in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/logout/')

    elif 'save' in request.POST:
        user = User.objects.get(username= request.user)
        user.user=request.POST.get('user')
                    user.name=request.POST.get('name')
        user.address=request.POST.get('address')
        user.designation=request.POST.get('designation')                        
        user.email=request.POST.get('email') 
        user.role=request.POST.get('role')
        user.project=request.POST.get('project')                        
        user.task=request.POST.get('task')
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/view_profile/')




                   # user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])

                    #drinker=user.get_profile();
                    #drinker.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
                    #drinker.address=form.cleaned_data['address']
                    #drinker.save()

    elif 'cancel' in request.POST:
        return                 HttpResponseRedirect('/view_profile/')               


user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
return render_to_response('edit_profile.html',{'profile':user_profile },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**HTML Template**

```
     {% block content %}

<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}    

    <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout" />
    <br/>
    User:
    <input type="text" name="user" value="{{ profile.user}}" /><br />
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ profile.name}}" /><br />

    Address:
    <input type="text" name="address" value="{{ profile.address}}" /><br />
    Designation:
    <input type="text" name="designation" value="{{ profile.designation}}" /><br />

    Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ profile.email}}" /><br />
    Role:
    <input type="text" name="role" value="{{ profile.role}}" /><br />

    Project:
    <input type="text" name="project" value="{{ profile.project}}" /><br />
    Task:
    <input type="text" name="task" value="{{ profile.task}}" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="cancel" />
    <br/>
</form>

   {% endblock %}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

`

Comment: It's not clear if you're trying to allow users to edit their own profile, or if you're trying to allow staff users to edit the profiles for other users. Which is it?

Comment: this is allow to user to edit their profile

Comment: don't do it in admin (users don't have access in there) & use `ModelForm` for it, it's much simplier.

Comment: How can i do it . any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
//equivalent to ex. (jay=1)
```

Maybe you should change this line to

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

or

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
```

Based in your code you define fields that are not in the User model

```
user = User.objects.get(username= request.user)
user.name=request.POST.get('name')
user.address=request.POST.get('address') <-----
user.designation=request.POST.get('designation') <----                        
user.email=request.POST.get('email') 
user.role=request.POST.get('role') <-----
user.project=request.POST.get('project') <----                       
user.task=request.POST.get('task') <-----
user.save()
```

I don't know where these fields came from. If you wish to save those information, you must define a separate model for that fields.

**UPDATE:**

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.POST:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        user.username=request.POST.get('user')                    
        user.email=request.POST.get('email') 
        user.save()

        employee = Employee.objects.get(user=request.user)
        employee.name=request.POST.get('name')
        employee.address=request.POST.get('address')
        employee.designation=request.POST.get('designation')                        
        employee.role=request.POST.get('role')
        employee.project=request.POST.get('project')                        
        employee.task=request.POST.get('task')
        employee.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/view_profile/')            

    user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
    return render_to_response('edit_profile.html',{
        'profile':user_profile 
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))


<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}    
    User:
    <input type="text" name="user" value="{{ profile.user.username}}" /><br />
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ profile.name}}" /><br />

    Address:
    <input type="text" name="address" value="{{ profile.address}}" /><br />
    Designation:
    <input type="text" name="designation" value="{{ profile.designation}}" /><br />

    Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ profile.email}}" /><br />
    Role:
    <input type="text" name="role" value="{{ profile.role}}" /><br />

    Project:
    <input type="text" name="project" value="{{ profile.project}}" /><br />
    Task:
    <input type="text" name="task" value="{{ profile.task}}" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="cancel" />
    <br/>
</form>
```

That's the way to save it but sorry I don't know your Employee model fields exactly so I just guess on it based on the variables you use.

Comment: Ok wait I will update my code because I found another issue in your code

Comment: here I have define a form in html file and using post method i pass the values.i checked 'request.POST.get('name')' & it pass the particular value. problem is not save these pass data in database table. I do not know why

Comment: `<input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="cancel" />`, reset not submit

Comment: Do you have extended model for User like UserProfile or I don't know what you name it?

Comment: Do you have any idea to add imagefiled to this one and uploads to sever?

Comment: @Lahiruzz you just have to create new field for image

Comment: then what should be the input type and how should I change the Views.py file?

Comment: @Lahiruzz `<input type="file" name="image"/>` and yes you have to change your view so that you can save the image together with them

Comment: how should I change views.py file. I changed but it does not work. plz help me

Comment: ::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034605/django-image-upload-to-the-server. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `request.user` is an instance of the Django model for the user who made the request, so the line...

```
user = User.objects.get(username= request.user)
```

...could simply be...

```
user = request.user
```

...but I could be wrong.

**Update**

It occurs to me that, if the original version of the code, which contained the line...

```
user = User.objects.get(username= request.user)
```

...didn't raise an exception, then it's possible it's not even being executed. If you're running from the Django built-in `runserver` command, try printing out the contents of the `request` variable at the top of the function.

Comment: In that case there's not really enough info to diagnose the problem. You may have to post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    slug_field = 'username'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(ProfileView, self).get_object(queryset)
        if not self.request.user or self.request.user.pk != obj.pk:
            raise Http404('nope')
        return obj
```

url route:

```
url(r'profileedit/(?P<username>[a-z-\d-]+)/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_view')
```

and template is obvious, I guess

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new form like this (myExample):

```
class userForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ['userName','name', 'lastName', 'email', 'description', 'image']}
```

Then in your views file and your method add the Form with an Object Instance Like:

```
myUser = User.objects.get(id=request.session['userId'])
form = userForm(request.POST, instance=myUser)
```

now you can pass this form with the fields full