# Django: Image Upload to the Server

Tags: django, django-models

I want to upload the image to the server. for that I have created a form and within my views.py file I tried to submit it into the sever. Here it does not uploads the file to "images" folder. instead of that it only update the database filed with new image name. So can anyone give me a solution.

this is views.py file

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):

if request.POST:


        employee = Employee.objects.get(user=request.user)          
        employee.avatar=request.POST.get('image')
        employee.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/view_profile/')       

user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
return render_to_response('edit_profile.html',{'profile':user_profile },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here my html code

```
   {% block content %}

<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}    

    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save" />        

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

what should i change to upload image to the "images" folder

Comment: should be ``request.FILES.get('image')``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` element, so that files are also uploaded and available in `request.FILES` in the view..

So update it to

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

 ....
```

More info at [Binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form)

To save the image its easier to use `ModelForm` and set image file appropriately. But still you want to save the object directly do

```
...
employee.avatar = request.FILES['image']
employee.save()
```

Ref [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: it changes database filed but does not upload the image to the "images" folder. is there any code for uploading image?

Comment: @Lahiruzz, I will suggest using `ModelForm` then rather than saving directly the object.

Comment: there is a mistake done by myself. now it's work. thanks for the help